# Replace < > with sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace parameters in a config file using sed.  The parameters are clearly marked as "". 
I'm trying to change

```
answer: <YOUR ANSWER HERE>
```

to

```
answer: answer
```

My sed command:

```
sed -i '/s/<ADD ANSWER HERE>/answer/' config.yaml
```

error is

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `<'
```

I've tried using "  and escaping with \<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply have an extra `/` at the beginning, which confused sed into thinking that you want to perform a command (called `<`) on a line that matches the pattern `/s/`. Instead, use:

```
sed -i 's/<ADD ANSWER HERE>/answer/' config.yaml
```